# how to set up your Laravel-WebSockets via SSL

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ssl, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

The Problem is **Laravel-Websockets** and **Laravel-Echo** combination works fine until you want to secure the connection by using SSL `HTTP -> HTTPS`
so I installed SSL Certificate on LocalHost (xampp, also I tried that on the live server too and got the same error) and changed the `forceTLS: false` to `forceTLS: true,` but I keep getting the **Provisional headers are shown** error on chrome network tab I even tried **Laravel CORS**

bootstrap.js be like :

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    devMode : true,

});
```

broadcast.php be like :

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                'host' => 'websocket8.test', // I read somewhere it's better to use domain name when we are working with HTTPS
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME'),
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

if you asking for .env file :

```
PUSHER_APP_ID={a random id}
PUSHER_APP_KEY={a random key}
PUSHER_APP_SECRET={a random secret}
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
PUSHER_SCHEME=http

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT="E:/Software/Xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt"
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK="E:/Software/Xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key"

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

chrome network tab error is like this:

[image: Provisional headers are shown]

Comment: I think your PUSHER_SCHEME should be https and also if you're using private channels you should set authHost and authEndpoint in bootstrap.js

Comment: @Rubens I've tried the HTTPS scheme but doesn't matter, and I think the problem is something about Cross-origin policy

Comment: share your websockets.php from config folder

Comment: `'verify_peer' => false` in websockets.php and restart all services

Comment: @Usman already did that but I don't think that's the problem because the laravel-echo can't connect to wss:// .... /6001 I think that's because the main port is 443 and the wss port is 6001 so there should be a cors problem but I did everything to fix that nothing works

Comment: Once I fixed this issue in past, Let me check what could be the possibilities.

Comment: have you tried it in another browser?

Comment: Sometimes it could be an apache error.

Comment: https://ibb.co/3TXQmt0 bootstrap.js

Comment: https://ibb.co/sRZk6Xm broadcasting.php